# If the roots of ${x^3}+3x+1=0$ are a, b and c then find the value of $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$

Tags: polynomials

I tried using Vieta's relation and wanted to somehow generate a term which would cancel out using $abc=-1$ but was unsuccessful..

Comment: Try Vieta's relation again.

Comment: I you know about discriminants, use that knowledge. If not, take the square of that value and use Vieta's relations on that (the square is symmetric in $a,b,c$).

Comment: @uniquesolution Using the Vieta's relations is not enough, since the expression is not symmetric in $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: One can only determine the value up to sign, since permuting the labels of the roots, e.g., by $a \leftrightarrow b$ reverses the sign. On the other hand the square of the expression is just the discriminant of the polynomial, which is invariant under permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
P = (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)
$$
Notice
$$
(a-b)^3 = a^3 - b^3 - 3ab(a-b)
$$
and
$$
a^3 + 3a + 1 = 0
$$
$$
b^3 + 3b + 1 = 0
$$
so that
$$
a^3 - b^3 = -3(a-b)
$$
Then we have
$$
(a-b)^3 = -3(1+ab)(a-b)
$$
Then
$$
P^3 = -27(1+ab)(1+bc)(1+ac)P
$$
$$
P^2 = -27(1 + ac + bc + ab + b^2ac + a^2bc + c^2ab + a^2b^2c^2) = -27(1 + 3 + abc(a+b+c) + 1) = -135
$$
$$
P = \pm\sqrt{135}i
$$
Depending on the actual values of $a,b,c$, the result is either $\sqrt{135}i$ or $-\sqrt{135}i$.